# Eclipse -- no me deja seguir, que hago?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, eclipse-oxygen

Estoy importando un proyecto de Java en Eclipse y no me deja seguir, me aparece esto.
He intentado buscar el ítem que falta, no encuentro en GOOGLE forma de instalarlo o como hacerlo. No me deja darle ni NEXT ni BACK, esta congelado en esta parte. He probado a desplegar mi proyecto también en INTELLIJ, me da el mismo problema. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y probaste instalar eso que dice que falta?

Comment: Como se instala, porque no encuentro nada por google

Comment: ¿Qué tal dar a "Next"? Además te lo ha marcado en azul, más fácil imposible.

Comment: No me deja darle a next. Tengo este mismo problema en intellij

Comment: ¿Tienes Maven instalado?

Comment: Si, eso no me falla en dependencias.